# How to Extract a claim from JWT payload in DataPower and insert into the header before pushing it to server in request flow

Tags: jwt, header, ibm-datapower

In DataPower we have a requirement to extract  the “onpremisessamaccountname” from the JWT token and insert into the header “user” before sending to Backend server.
How can we do this using XSLT code or is there any possible way to achieve this in DataPower?

I will be grateful for any help with example

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a AAA, I'm pretty sure there is a JWT check that will validate the signature and throw the claims into context variables.

Otherwise a JWT is mostly base64 encoded JSON so shouldn't be too difficult to decode and regex out the value you want.

Comment: it would be nice if you could supply code / config example or some link to elaborate more on your answer